# I am not getting the textbox value in typescript angular7

Tags: angular, typescript, scripting

I'm using angular7. Just make some textbox and then alert that textbox value. But I can't get the values in typescript.
Please help me guys how to proceed more this step.

**about.component.html**

```
<input type="text" name="username">
<button (click)="lgbtnclick()" type="button" name="button"></button>
```

**about.component.ts**

```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  @Component({
  selector: 'app-about',
  templateUrl: './about.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./about.component.scss']
  })

  export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {
   name : string;

   constructor() { }

   ngOnInit() {
   }

   lgbtnclick(){
      alert(this.name)
      console.log(Error)
   }
}
```

alert message:

```
undefined
```

Comment: shoe us the html

Comment: Its now showing

Comment: use `ngmodel` to bind textbox value to name varible .name is undefined it's not initialized

Comment: Try: `<input type="text" name="username" [(ngModel)]="name">`

Comment: Can you give suggestion then how to implement in typescript?

Comment: Check out this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ga6rry

Comment: @PrashantPimpale What are the module means dependence packages to install system?

Comment: Unable to understand the question

Comment: My doubt is what are the package must install in my system?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set default value to `""` for `name` property and use `[(ngModel)]="name"` for input type

HTML Code:

```
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Enter name" [(ngModel)]="name" >
  </mat-form-field>

  <button (click)="lgbtnclick()" type="button" name="button">Test</button>
```

TS Code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'input-overview-example',
  styleUrls: ['input-overview-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'input-overview-example.html',
})
export class InputOverviewExample {
  name: string="";

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  lgbtnclick() {
    alert(this.name)
    console.log(Error)
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ga6rry)

Comment: Its showing console log
**ƒ Error() { [native code] }**

Comment: Remove this:`console.log(Error)`

Comment: Without typing anything its always return empty string

Comment: I'm using your code what you enter in dev live server. that same code in my page

Comment: Just forked it and share the link

Comment: Is there any API Call?

Comment: Show .ts Code for about componnt

Comment: i'm attached my screen shot below please find that one.

Comment: import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-about',
  templateUrl: './about.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./about.component.scss']
})
 export class AboutComponent{
   name: string="";

     constructor() { }

     ngOnInit() {
     }

     lgbtnclick() {
     alert(this.name)
     //console.log(Error)
   }
  }

Comment: Its perfectly fine might be issue related to `ng serve`>

Comment: how can I fix this?

Comment: if possible then share anydesk id will have a look@

Comment: I don't know how to do that

Comment: just  now i tried this command **alert({name})** 
its showing alert **[object object]**

Answer (score 1):

Angulars data binding differs from jQuery or plain JavaScript and won't work using the "name" attribute of the `input` element. Please refer to either [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) or [Template driven Forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms).

In your example, the template driven form could be applied. Angular works by binding the value of an input to that of an instance variable of the hosting class with `[(ngModel)]="name"`. Though it is discouraged to do it, the `[` and `(` refer to a property AND event binding (two-way data binding). Find out more about it [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html).

To use the `ngModel` directive, you need to include the `FormsModule` in your respective module.

**The HTML code:**

```
<input matInput placeholder="Enter name" [(ngModel)]="name" >
<button (click)="lgbtnclick()" type="button" name="button"></button>
```

**The Typescript code:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-about',
  styleUrls: ['about.component.css'],
  templateUrl: 'about.component.html',
})
export class AboutComponent {
  name: string="";

  constructor() { }

  lgbtnclick() {
    alert(this.name)
    console.log(Error)
  }
}
```

Comment: This is also showing like this **ƒ Error() { [native code] }**

Comment: Please remove this line `console.log(Error)` and post the complete console output if there are any errors.

Comment: Can I know why its showing like this issue ** ƒ Error() { [native code] }** ?

Comment: Because `Error` in console.log(Error) apparently evaluates  ** ƒ Error() { [native code] }**

Answer (score 1):

Hi the name attribute in your html code doesn't actually bind to your typescript file. It's just an attribute on the HTMLElement. If you want that value there are actually a lot of options. The simplest solution here is just attach the name variable to the value attribute of the input or good'ol `ngModel` (make sure to import ReactiveFormsModule and FormsModule in your AppModule)

## Value Solution

### html

```html
<input type="text" name="username" [value]="name">
<button (click)="lgbtnclick()" type="button" name="button"></button>
```

### ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
@Component({
  selector: "app-about",
  templateUrl: "./about.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./about.component.scss"]
})
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {
  name: string;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  lgbtnclick() {
    alert(this.name);
    console.log(Error);
  }
}
```

## ngModel Solution

### html

```html
<input type="text" name="username" [(ngModel)]="name">
<button (click)="lgbtnclick()" type="button" name="button"></button>
```

### ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
@Component({
  selector: "app-about",
  templateUrl: "./about.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./about.component.scss"]
})
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {
  name: string;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  lgbtnclick() {
    alert(this.name);
    console.log(Error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Now also display empty

Comment: what method did you use? ngModel or the value?

Comment: I'm not using method only this two lines in html file.

Comment: Guys still i'm facing same issue.